# How do I compare json_key_dots with json_key_brackets?

Tags: python, json, brackets

I have two files to compare and insert into second file missing key_value or update existing key with new value.
the problem for me is that first file has dots to separate keys:

```
{"a.b.c":0}
```

second file looks like:

```
{"a":{"b":{"c":0}}}
```

Comment: If you're looking for some sort of "built-in" functionality to do this, I don't think it exists. You're going to have to write a function to convert between the formats.

Comment: @glibdud, thank you for your comment(and negative rating),
I'm here cause I broke my head trying to write such function.

Comment: If you can show the code you're having trouble with and describe what it's doing wrong and what you expect it to do, you stand a much better chance of getting quality help. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to deal with something similar. This is what I came up with:

```
def to_flat_dict(d, delim='.'):
    """TLDR;
    While there are entries in the dictionary that have a dict as a value:
        pop them at the outer level and create a delimited path as a key, eg:
            {'a': {'b': {'c': 0}}} -> {'a.b': {'c': 0}}
            # by same process
            {'a.b': {'c': 0}} -> {'a.b.c': 0}
    """
    flat = dict(d)   # work on a copy
    incomplete = list(flat)  
    while(incomplete):
        k = incomplete.pop()
        if isinstance(flat[k], dict):
            val = flat.pop(k)
            for subk, subv in val.items():
                new_key = delim.join((k, subk))
                flat[new_key] = subv
                incomplete.append(new_key)
    return flat


def to_nested_dict(d, delim='.'):
    """TLDR;
    
    flat: {"a.b.c":0}
    # pop 'a.b.c' and value 0 and break key into parts
    parts:  ['a','b','c']:
    
    # process 'a'
    flat <- {'a':dict()} 
    # process 'b'
    flat <- {'a': {'b': dict()}} 
    # process 'c' @ tmp[parts[-1]] = val
    flat <- {'a': {'b': {'c': 0}}} 

    """
    flat = dict(d) # work on a copy
    keys = list(d) # we copy the keys since we are modifying the dict in place
    for key in keys:
        # Basic idea: for all keys that contain the delim
        if delim in key:
            val = flat.pop(key)
            # get the parts (a.b.c -> [a, b, c])
            parts = key.split(delim)
            # we start with the outer dict, but as we process parts of the key
            level = flat # we assign level to the newly created deeper dicts
            for part in parts[:-1]:
                if part not in level:   # if the part isn't a key at this depth
                    level[part] = dict() # create a new dict to fill
                level = level[part]      # and work on the next deeper level
            level[parts[-1]] = val # when we get to the "leaf" set it as val
    return flat
```

You can get your desired nested dict by calling:

```
to_nested_dict({'a.b.c':0})
```

You can invert this with *to_flat_dict*:

```
to_flat_dict(to_nested_dict({'a.b.c':0})) # back to {'a.b.c':0}
```

Your mileage may vary!

Comment: thank you for reply!
# Basic idea: for all keys that contain the delim - delimiter is a dot, but value also can contain a dot for example IP address.

Comment: @bay You need to do a bit of extra work yourself for this, it totally depends on your assumptions and requirements. You could add another delimiter that you parse as "verbatim" --- wrap the url in something (modify the split such that it only splits when not in the "verbatim" environment). Another alternative would be to check against a list of regexes in order to decide if you will split the key or not.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code that works for me but I hate it, especially ff_function.
I think it should be done using recursive function- don't know how to :(

```
>>> def ff(k, d, i, v):
...   if i == len(k)-1:
...     last_value = v 
...   else:
...     last_value = {}
...   if i == 0:
...     d[k[0]] = last_value
...   elif i == 1:
...     d[k[0]][k[1]] = last_value
...   elif i == 2:
...     d[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]] = last_value
...   elif i == 3:
...     d[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]][k[3]] = last_value
...   elif i == 4:
...     d[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]][k[3]][k[4]] = last_value
...   elif i == 5:
...     d[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]][k[3]][k[4]][k[5]] = last_value
...   return d
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def f(k, v):
...   td = {}
...   keys = k.split('.')
...   for i in range(len(keys)):
...     td = ff(keys, td, i, v)
...   return td
... 
>>> 
>>> f('a.b.c.d', ['some', 'values', 'here'])
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': ['some', 'values', 'here']}}}}
>>> f('a', 0)
{'a': 0}
```

Comment: You have the basic idea down :) So you need to find the pattern that is repeated in your ff function to simplify your code and generalize it to work for any number of key parts (what if your key has 10 parts?). Note that you are always adding a key to d and setting a value, but d is different depending on the "depth". Think of a way of passing d to be the part of the dictionary at the appropriate depth, that way you can break the problem into subproblems  which can be solved using the same code. If you get stuck, check what the last 9 lines of to_nested_dict do.